# Remove trailing and leading whitespaces with Ecto changeset

Tags: elixir, ecto

Is there a built-in way in Ecto to remove trailing and leading whitespaces of fields in `Ecto.Changeset` when calling `changeset/2` before inserting it to the database?

---

At the moment, I am adding two custom functions to my schema for data filtering to improve data integrity:

```
defp trim_fields(changeset, fields) do
  Enum.reduce(fields, changeset, &trim(&2, &1))
end

defp trim(changeset, field) do
  if get_change(changeset, field) do
    update_change(changeset, field, &String.trim/1)
  else
    changeset
  end
end
```

The function(s) can then be piped in the `changeset/2` function with, e.g.

```
def changeset(%Customer{} = customer, attrs) do
  |> cast(attrs, [:first_name, :last_name])
  |> validate_required([:first_name], [:last_name])
  |> trim_fields([:first_name, :last_name])
end
```

Since I think this is a common use-case I was wondering if there isn't a function that already provides this functionality?

If this functionality is not yet provided in Ecto, then from the Ectos API point of view, it would be convenient to add such functions and by naming them `filter_trim` and `filter_...` I guess?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think it's best to trim input before running validations. Also, `update_change` will only perform the change if there is a change for the given key.

This leads to slightly more streamlined code:

```
changeset
|> cast(attrs, [:first_name, :last_name])
|> update_change(:first_name, &String.trim/1)
|> update_change(:last_name, &String.trim/1)
|> validate_required([:first_name, :last_name])
```

Comment: I overlooked the fact that `update_change` only executes the given function when there is a change for the given key. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to extend zwippie's great answer.

As the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.10.3/Ecto.Changeset.html#update_change/3) points out, the value may be `nil` if the field was cleared. Thus, I'd use something like this:

```
def changeset(%Customer{} = customer, attrs) do
  customer
  |> cast(attrs, [:first_name, :last_name])
  |> update_change(:first_name, &trim/1)
  |> update_change(:last_name, &trim/1)
  |> validate_required([:first_name, :last_name])
end

defp trim(binary) when is_binary(binary), do: String.trim(binary)
defp trim(nil), do: nil
```

And if you have many fields you want to do the trimming on, I would consider defining an auxiliary function `update_changes/3` (similar to your `trim_fields/2`):

```
def changeset(%Customer{} = customer, attrs) do
  customer
  |> cast(attrs, [:first_name, :last_name])
  |> update_changes([:first_name, :last_name], &trim/1)
  |> validate_required([:first_name, :last_name])
end

defp update_changes(changeset, keys, function) do
  Enum.reduce(keys, changeset, fn key, set -> update_change(set, key, function) end)
end
```

Comment: I would prefer this one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `:trim`?

```
changeset
|> cast(attrs, [:first_name, :last_name])
|> validate_required([:first_name, :last_name], [trim: true])
```

Docs [validate_required/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.9.2/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_required/3:%7E:text=%3Atrim%20%2D%20a%20boolean%20that%20sets%20whether%20whitespaces%20are%20removed%20before%20running%20the%20validation).

Comment: According to the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.9.2/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_required/3-options), the `trim` option for `validate_required/3` is only removing whitespace for the validation, (so that multiple whitespaces like `"    "` would still count as empty value), and the option already defaults to `true`. So `trim: true` does not actually change the cast value and keeps surrounding whitespace.